# Using row values in ng-grid column cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to add a column that have a link to another page (is an ng-grid table). That link contains one of the values of the row

I tried something like this:

```
$scope.columns = [
  {field:'id', displayName:'#'},
  {field:'name', displayName:'Name'},
  {field:'view', displayName:'Action', cellTemplate: '<a href="http://foo.com/person/' +  {row.getProperty(col.id)} + '">[View Details]</a>'}
];
```

But is not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression should be

`{{row.getProperty(col.id)}}`

or

`{{row.getProperty(\'id\')}}`

Answer (score 2):

or you can

```
{{row.entity[\'id\']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-grid property COL_FIELD:

```
{{COL_FIELD}}
```

For example:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText">{{COL_FIELD | date}}</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below :

```
cellTemplate : href="https://localhost:8082{{row.entity.ImgLink}}"
```